# How can I make a Windows Phone textblock lost focus?

Tags: windows-phone, textblock

As you know we can use method `this.textblock1.focus()` to get focus, but if I want to make textblock lost focus, is there any method exists?

Comment: this.Focus() will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give focus to some other control.

Answer (score 1):

```
textblock1.MoveFocus(new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Next));
```